# Create and deploy EJB applications without using an IDE

Tags: jakarta-ee, ide, ejb-3.0

I have created EJB applications using NetBeans 7.1.1. It was like all the work was done by IDE itself. So, I would like to create and deploy EJB 2.0 applications without an IDE. Any help informing how to proceed would be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning EJB JavaEE 1.4 Spec without an IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675269/learning-ejb-javaee-1-4-spec-without-an-ide)